# Solve functional integral equations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I encountered one problem which is to find $F(\lambda)$ which satisfies
$1 = \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i k \lambda} dF(\lambda), \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the answer is $F(\lambda) = 1$ if $\lambda \ge 0$ and 0 otherwise.

I would like to solve it using mathematica, but a naive approach such as `RSolve[1 == Integrate[Exp[I  k  x], {F[x], -Pi, Pi}], F, x, Assumptions -> Integers[k]]` doesn't seem to work. The error message says

```
Supplied equations are not difference equations of the given functions.
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `F[x_]:=HeavisideTheta[x]` then $dF=\delta(x)dx$, hence $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ikx}dF=1$. The code is

```
F = HeavisideTheta[x]; Integrate[Exp[I k x] D[F, x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> k > 0]
```

Comment: @yarchik Any way we can't solve it with Mathematica as it is. May be you mean some numerical solution then it could be interesting to see how solution turns to `HeavisideTheta[x]`.

Comment: To have a constructive solution one may Fourier transform with respect to $k$ the left and right hand sides.